# Need help: input int from console and pass it into method in different class

Tags: java, syntax, io

I'm a beginner. I want to read a number `a` from the console and then store them in variable to use as passing to a different class (different `.java` file).

How do I code the 2 classes?

```
public class PassedInMethod{ 

   private int a;

   public PAssMethod(int a) { 
      a = a; // TODO: where to get the a? 
      System.out.println("a was passed in!"+a);
   }
} 



public class Mainclass {

  public static void main( String args[] ) {
      Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );

      int a;

      System.out.print( "Enter your nember: " );
      a = input.nextInt();

      PassedInMethod(int a);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**If you want to create an instance** of the `PassedInMethod` class in which the member variable `a` contains the value passed to the constructor.

Try changing

```
PassedInMethod(int a);
```

to

```
PassedInMethod myObj = new PassedInMethod(a);
```

Also, if you want to update the instance variable to the value of the argument you need to do

```
this.a = a;
```

since the argument "hides" the instance varuable.

**If you don't want to create an instance**, and just invoke a method in a different class, you need to make the method static like this:

```
public static void PassMethod(int a) {
    // ....
}
```

You could then call the method like this

```
PassedInMethod.passMethod(a);
```

---

`PassedInMethod` however is not a very good name for a class, but I'm sure that was just for the sake of the example in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
PassedInMethod(int a);
```

To

```
new PassedInMethod(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be more of what you want. You code had some syntax errors and such.

```
public class PassedInMethod {
    private int a;

    public PAssMethod(int a) { 
        this.a = a;
        System.out.println("a was passed in!"+a);
    }
}

public class Mainclass {
    public static void main( String args[] ) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
        int a;

        System.out.print( "Enter your nember: " );
        a = input.nextInt();

        PassedInMethod myobj = new PassedInMethod();
        myobj.PAssMethod(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: "this.a is more complete, but not required.". It is required. Otherwise you just have `a = a;` which is equivalent to a nop.

Comment: My bad. I was thinking of something else. Thanks for having my back :)

Comment: sorry for my typo.
the "PassMethod()", I mean "PassedInMethod()".

Can I change "PassMethod()" to "PassedInMethod()" in the corrected code?